# Как записать данные в фаил?

Tags: java, android

Пишу простейшую конструкцию:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(file.getName(),MODE_PRIVATE);
            String i = "string";
            fos.write(i.getBytes());
            fos.close();
```

Но в фаил ничего не записывается!
Если напишу так:

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
 String i = "string";
 fos.write(i.getBytes());
 fos.close();
```

То слово "string" запишется.
Что не так с openFileOutput ?

Comment: Забыл добавить, что в обоих случаях все компилируется и прекрасно работает, не выдавая никаких Exception' ов.

Comment: попробуйте fos.flush(); добавить перед fos.close(); если не поможет покажите реализацию метода openFileOutput.

Answer (score 1):

Прикладываю код метода для записи данных в файл:

```
private void writeToFile(String data,Context context) {
try {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    outputStreamWriter.write(data);
    outputStreamWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: Ваш метод ничего в фаил не пишет)) Как было 0 байт, так и осталось

Comment: @Basic_Linuxoid а вы пермишены прописали?

Comment: Прописал. android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Прописать мало, их нужно ещё и вызывать авно для последний версий андроида. У вас это тоже есть?

Comment: да, есть. Запрашиваю разрешение методом requestPermissions.

Comment: Кстати если использовать FileWriter, то строка тоже пишется в фаил)) Тут что то именно с openFileOutput, поскольку только используя его, на выходе фаил остается 0 байт.

Comment: @Basic_Linuxoid так решили проблему? Узнали почему не пишется?

Comment: нет. Я не знаю, что делать)) openFileOutput просто ничего не делает.